# Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package framework is missing the framework dependency declaration in the manifest

Tags: windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit, wack

I receive the following error on the Windows App Certification Kit for Windows 8.1.

> The app manifest test detected the following errors:XXX takes a
>   dependency on Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package
>   (Microsoft.VCLibs.110.00) framework but is missing the framework
>   dependency declaration in the manifest.

My solution builds with zero errors. However, I receive an error after I create an app package and run the Windows Application Certification Kit.

I have added and removed references to the C++ runtime extension.
In addition, I do not see any fields in the app manifest editor to modify that would resolve this dependency error.

Comment: Hi, I almost voted to close your question; it was not at all clear what it was about. Tagging a question Windows and adding WACK in the body does not help anyone find what you're talking about... I've changed the tags to something more appropriate. Are you able to [edit] your question with an explanation of when you receive the error. All we know is that you get one.

Comment: "after I create an app package".  If you do this yourself instead of letting the build system take care of it then you are doing it wrong.  We can't see you doing it wrong.

Comment: Startup project -> Store | Create App Package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are including a library that was built with Visual Studio 2012. You will need to rebuild that library in Visual Studio 2013. If you just have the binary you will need to get an updated version from the author.

..
Or 
Rename "Microsoft.VCLibs.110" to Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.110.00",

Or

Add a reference in your project to `Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package`

Add reference and find this Package. Adding this should resolve your problem

Comment: I actually solved this before your answer. However, your answer is still correct. I had a literal dll file added as a file to one of my projects. The file was no longer relevant and as a result I removed it. That actually resolved my error.